# Rstudio How to suppress console messages until end of script

Tags: r, rstudio

When running a script with a large number of lines RStudio always lags and freezes due to the output/echo that appears in the console. Is there any way to suppress the console messages entirely or at least suppress the repetition of the input that occurs when a script is run?

Comment: You can source without echo (Ctrl+Shift+S on windows).